# Date YYYY-MM-DDのフォーマット形式にしたいが、getFullYearが存在しない関数のように言われます。

Tags: javascript

Dateを YYYY-MM-DDのフォーマット形式にしたいです。
getFullYearが存在しない関数のように言われます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function
    at formatDate
happens
```

**ソースコード:**

```
    function formatDate(date){

        var month = ("0"+(date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var date =  ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);

        var formatted = `${date.getFullYear()}-${month}-${date}`.replace(/\n|\r/g,'');
        return formatted;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> var date =  ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);

これで`date`を上書きしちゃっているからですね。